# LinkButton sometimes requires two clicks

Tags: javascript, .net-4.0, webforms

I have an ASP.NET 4.0 Web Forms app and I'm using jQuery to do most of the JavaScript. The problem I'm having is that some of the links sometimes require two clicks for them to do anything.

Seemingly this happens at random and I have been unsuccessful in reproducing the problem in any kind of repeatable fashion, also there don't seem to be any JavaScript errors, so that's *probably* not the issue.

I'm at a loss as to what might be causing the issue. What might it be?

Answer (score 0):

Without a view of your Javascript, HTML or backend code, there's not much I can suggest as to what might be causing the problem.

However, if you have Firebug installed, you could use that to see what clicking the button is doing each time and go from there.

Also... what is it supposed to do? What does it do the first time? These are questions that will need answers before debug assistance can be provided

Comment: All fair points, I'm trying to get something more concrete. In terms of what's supposed to happen, it varies, some links do a post back others call JavaScript. There's seemingly little in common with the links that cause the problem.